# How to set value to new column in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

This is probably in another question, but I cannot find it.

I am a relative noobie to Rails.  I am trying to add a new column to a table that already has data in it.  This column is not going to allow nulls.  What is the easiest way to update all the existing records to have a value in this new column?  I know it is probably in the up block of my migration, but I don't know what the syntax would be.

```
def self.up
  change_table :reminders do |t|
    t.boolean :active
  end
  #model name is Reminder - how to update data with a value?
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is add the column, update all records in the table with the desired value, then change it to not allow nulls.

```
def self.up
  add_column :reminders, :active, :boolean, :default => true
  Reminder.update_all( "active = ?", true )
  change_column :reminders, :active, :boolean, :default => true, :null => :false
end
```

Comment: this seemed to work on my dev copy.  It seems to fail though on Heroku though.

Comment: Everything fails on Heroku :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def self.up
  change_table :reminders do |t|
   t.boolean :active, :default => true #or your value
  end
#model name is Reminder - how to update data with a value?
end
```